# In order to change your profile you have to connect your account to PAUSE

Tags: metacpan

I just opened an account at https://metacpan.org and wanted to edit my profile. However, CPAN requires a `PAUSE` account.

> In order to change your profile you have to connect [your account to PAUSE](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/oauth2/authorize?client_id=metacpan.org&choice=pause).

When I click on the link, a pop-up says: `Please enter your PAUSE ID:`

The error appears on the [Profile](https://metacpan.org/account/profile) page.

What is a PAUSE ID? Googling it brings me to booking websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAUSE stands for **The [Perl programming] Authors Upload Server** at https://pause.perl.org

**Registering as a developer**

> Registered developers have a unique username and a home directory in
> the authors/id/ tree of CPAN. The write access to that directory is
> password protected.
>
> If you have written a module, script, or documentation you would like
> to contribute to the archive, visit pause.perl.org Registration
> (Non-SSL version) and fill in the form. You will be notified by email
> about your registration. Please allow three weeks for proceeding,
> which should be the maximum during vacation time. Normally we hope to
> register you within a week.